# How many 5-letter words with a) no letter A b) at least one A

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So I've got the problem "How many 5-letter words can be made if the alphabet has 29 letters and 
a) the letter A doesn't show once and 
b) the letter A shows at least once.

For A) I counted it as 28!/23! since you only have 28 letters to really think about without A?
But I'm really stuck with B, so if anyone could help me, that would be appreciated!

Comment: Are we saying that e.g. $ADBHS$ counts as a word?

Comment: Apparently yes, the question doesn't specify that the words have to make sense

Answer (score 2):

> How many five-letter words can be made if the alphabet has $29$ letters and the letter A is not used once?

If no A is used, there are $29 - 1 = 28$ ways to fill each position, so there are $28^5$ possible five-letter words that do not contain an A.

Your answer 
$$P(28, 5) = \frac{28!}{(28 - 5)!} = \frac{28!}{23!}$$
would be correct if letters could not be repeated.

> How many five-letter words can be made if the alphabet has $29$ letters and the letter A is used at least once?

The set of five-letter words in which the letter A is used at least once is the complement of the set of five-letter words in which the letter A is not used once.  To find the answer, subtract the number of five-letter words in which the letter A is not used once from the number of five-letter words that can be formed from the alphabet.

Comment: Thank you so much!